# Plural of "must have"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I have seen on a clothing advertisement something like the following:

> This Summer "Must Haves"!

Is it correct? For example, one swimsuit is one "must have" and two swimsuits are two "must haves."

Answer (score 2):

Saying that something "is a must-have" is not a grammatically correct sense, it's very informal. But yes, the plural would be "these are both must-haves". And by the way, you can either put "must have" in quotes like you did above, or you can hyphenate it like I just did here.

Side note: The plural of "suit" is "suits", not "suites". A "suite", plural "suites", is a group of connected rooms in a larger building, like a "hotel suite", meaning that the space the traveler is renting in the hotel is several rooms, like a bedroom and a separate lounging area; or an "office suite", meaning that the space the company is renting in the office building consists of several offices, a reception area, whatever.

Comment: -1.  It's not ungrammatical at all.

Comment: Hmm. "This swimsuit is a must have." The construction calls for a predicate adjective, like "This swimsuit is red" or "This swimsuit is sexy." But "have" is a verb. It is not grammatically correct to use a verb as an adjective. I suppose you could say that "must-have" is being used as an adjective, but by that reasoning, there is no such thing as a grammatically incorrect sentence. You could always say that you are "using a noun as a verb" or "using a singular as a plural".

Comment: Sure, *have* is a verb.  But the adjective *must-have*, like the noun *must-have*, is lexicalized.  It is no longer simply a combination of *must* with *have*.  See [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/must-have).

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The phrase comes from the imperative *you must have*, used here in the sense of *you are required to possess*. This is not a noun or a noun phrase, so in standard English it is an incorrect usage to pluralize *"must have"*.

The given usage isn't standard English, however, but advertising. *You must have this*. The phrase itself is a command: *You are required to possess this amazing bathing suit/fast car/hi-tech device.* The objects being advertised are implied to be essentials, necessary items without which the person being advertised to cannot hope to have a fulfilled life.

Of course, because this IS advertising, they can't simply call things "essential items".  The logical marketing-speak alternative is to use a nouned form of the verb phrase. Thus, the new bathing suit without which your life is incomplete becomes a "must-have" item. From there, it is reasonable to pluralize the nouned compound word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I am under no illusions that the phrase is younger than I am. It was more of a tongue-in-cheek explanation of the thought process behind coining the phrase, rather than any serious belief that it is recent. Looking it over, the original form of that third paragraph was too prescriptivist, so I rewrote it to be more neutral.

Comment: Ech. "Younger than I am" comes across as snarky, not what I intended. "Recent as opposed to non-recent" was the intention behind it, not snark.

Comment: @ Jonathan: Following your comments (and edit, *and* the fact that you quietly switched OP's rather odd *swimming suit* to *bathing suit*), I'm deleting my earlier comment and upvoting the answer. I don't really think nounified "must have" is exclusively "ad-speak", but it's certainly strongly associated with marketing (and "fashionista" columnists).